# How should I handle the rails asset pipeline for uploaded images that change the scope of their public view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline

After reading about how rails is handling image assets, I am confused and am having trouble deciding where to keep uploaded images in my app's directory tree.  If a user has uploaded an image to my rails app, should I make the image_save_path /assets/images/ or /public/images  ?

My concern/question: If I want to allow users to make their images public when they choose to do so, should an uploaded image that is 'un-published' (image is served only if current_user == image.owner) be considered more protected if it resides in assets/images instead of public/images?  Equally protected?  Less protected somehow?

Am I right to assume that the benefit of using the asset pipeline for images is simply that the file names get hashed in production mode and that's it?  Is there some implied additional or diminished security here in terms of how the resource is served?  Is this more a matter of subtle opinion or does the rails convention have something to say here?

Thanks!

EDIT1:
How would you handle uploaded content that you want to make available to the uploading user, but not discoverable to guests or other users?  Should (can?) one store uploaded content outside the tree under web_root ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application assets are those assets that are part of your application, such as backgrounds and icons (in the case of images). The asset pipeline has nothing to do with user-uploaded images. I'd suggest to keep them separated, serve them from separate CDN if needed.

The hashing of filenames in the asset pipeline is done only during asset compilation, so a link to a specific image is made unique for the image contents. This helps to avoid setting complex caching headers to images and other assets, as when the image changes, the filename changes too, and the cached version won't be used at all.

All this does not apply to user-uploaded images, you are not going to compile on-the-fly the assets for their images.

Comment: Thanks rewritten.  So you would suggest keeping uploaded images in something like /public/images/uploaded  ?  What about the case when it is desireable to have uploaded images available to the uploading user, but not discoverable by the public?  I would not want an http request for www.mysite.com/images/uploaded to list directory contents.  Yet, I'd want rails to serve out content from the same location.  I thought keeping uploaded images outside the tree below web_root would be a good idea, but then the routing for resources seems complicated.